# How to pass id in url when user login with his detail

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink

hey every one i have on query plse help me

i want if user login with his login detail his id should be pass and should be visible in link bar ?id=000 like this.
i am trying lot but not able to resolve it plse help me guys...

```
<?php                   
include('db.php');
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
//$id= $_POST["id"];                                
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pwd = $_POST['pwd'];       

$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='$email' and pwd='$pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rows==1){

$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
header("Location:Employee/dashboard.php"); //here if user successfully log in his user id should be also visible in url bar

}else{

$query = "SELECT * FROM art WHERE email='$email' and pwd='$pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rows==1){

$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
header("Location:Recruiter/dashboard.php"); 
}else{

echo "<script>alert('Incorrect user id and password')</script>";
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You're going to need to clarify the question a little better.

Comment: now you can check it out plse through comment line

Comment: why you not using session for user data ? @Prem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the modification to your code that needs to be done. You will need to fetch `id` from the table, if the credentials are valid and append that `id` to the URL:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM register WHERE email='$email' and pwd='$pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(isset($rows['id']) && $rows['id'] > 0){

$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
header("Location:Employee/dashboard.php?id=" . $rows['id']);
```

Comment: You're welcome! You can up-vote and mark this as done. Happy Coding! :)

Comment: what i should do if i want keep id untill session is not destroyed or logout 
coz if i am visiting next page id is not hold as longer and i need this id to keep till user not logout.

Comment: Store the ID in the session `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $rows['id'];` and it will remain in session, until you destroy the session,

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to send user_id from POST or GET, Set user_id in session at login time. and fetch it from session where you need it..this is the best solution..

OR

You can send it in your form as a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$id}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you want to display id in URL ?After login, you can access it from the user session. If you still want then here is the code.

```
<pre>
$query = "SELECT id FROM art WHERE email='$email' and pwd='$pwd'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rows==1){
   $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
header("Location:Recruiter/dashboard.php?id=".$data['id']); 
}else{

echo "<script>alert('Incorrect user id and password')</script>";
    }
    }
}
</pre>
```

Comment: coz i have another table inside dashboard and i want retrive data of that table on the base of session id i try to retrive it through  session but it not working there.. thus i want hit user i to retrive data base on his id

Answer (score 0):

You probably get the answer from previous answers but I am adding this answer as the best practices to use the session to this kind of activity.

begins the session, you need to say this at the top of a page or before you call session code `session_start();`

put a user id in the session to track who is logged in `$_SESSION['user'] = $user_id;` . Then for Check if someone is logged in or not.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  // if logged in
} else {
  // if not logged in
}
```

Find the logged in user ID `$_SESSION['user']`.

Answer (score 0):

to redirect use this function:

```
function redirect($url){
    if (headers_sent()){
        die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href=\'' . $url . '\';</script>');
    }else{
        header('Location: ' . $url);
      die();
    }
}
```

save user id in `$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['user_id'];` and change your code like this:

```
if($rows==1){

$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
redirect(SITE_URL.'Employee/dashboard.php?id='.$_SESSION['id']); //here if user successfully log in his user id should be also visible in url bar

}
```

after user logged in check url everywhere you want like blow and if `id` not exist redirect again:

```
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
    $url = CURRENT_URL;
    $url .= '?id='.$_SESSION['id']; //or $url .= '&id='.$_SESSION['id'];  if some variables set befor 
    redirect($url);
}
```